# Weather2 vs Weather - how renaming mvc controller's action can result in ajax request failure?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

Hi I have MVC app with 1 View Index and several Partial Views that are being loaded into corresponded divs by jQuery.load() function. Now I see a very strange behaviour:

existing code:

```
    public ActionResult Weather()
    {
        return PartialView(WeatherManager.GetWeather());
    }
```

and

```
$('#weather').load('Home/Weather');
```

Generates this javascript error:

[image]

Note, the action is not being invoked at all, it's like ajax call is blocked.

**However!**, if I just rename controller's action to **Weather2**

and change jQuery call to **$('#weather').load('Home/Weather2');**

then everything just works :)

I have no clue why this would happen.

There is not a single code change, just renamed Weather to Weather2, that's all.

Any ideas?

P.S>  I didnt want to overcomplicate the question with google oauth code behind, simply because that Weather action is not using google oauth, Google Oauth is used in two other actions (Calendar and Gmail). And yes, it's unclear to me why the request to google oauth is involved here at all. Providing more details, tracing shows that renaming the action Weather2 -> Weather results in Response Headers being changed, here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Another thing - is when I am navigating directly to `http://localhost/Homepage/Home/Weather` the request is being redirected to

```
http://localhost/Homepage/AuthCallback/IndexAsync?state=http://localhost/Homepage/Home/Weather43537229&code=4/ZQExqQ1-1PvS87bn87g986t98y6bcnXfry4RuzdyAQkTgDNMs.Ym8n4sn9PwjkhIBIB0ZRONyF65E5ZflQI
```

and fails:

[image]

However after renaming action to Weather2, and nsvigating to it `http://localhost/Homepage/Home/Weather2`, everything miraculously works:

[image]

How is that possible ???

Comment: since error is related to google oauth it doesn't appear you have provided all of the details related to your app that are pertininet

Comment: You are right, I know, because other details are irrelevant. I didnt want to overcomplicate the question because I wouldnt get a single response back :) What important is that Weather action has nothing to do with Google Oauth, Google Oauth is used in two other actions (Calendar and Gmail). And yes, it's unclear to me why the request to google oauth is involved here at all. Besides, think about it - just renaming the action results in JS request error? WTF? The other thing - when running the site (having Weather action) from another machine, at different IP, the damn thing works :)

Comment: Let me know if you want to see the Oauth code, but it rather irrelevant and is not used by the Weather action at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!
That was a damn orphan application (or phantom app or zombie app) stuck in IIS hosting :)
There are some related articles to that:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1500.hunting-zombies-how-to-remove-orphaned-iis-web-applications.aspx

https://serverfault.com/questions/283467/removing-phantom-applications-from-application-pools-in-iis7

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Aug/09/Editing-Applicationhostconfig-on-64-bit-Win2008

I found editing c:\windows\system32\inetsvr\config\applicationhost.config - the easiest way to solve the problem with zombie app.

god, it takes time to find the damn thing...